# Rewrite userdir for users that changed the username

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-userdir

This seems simple, but I wasn't able to do it.

I have a user that changed his username from `givenname` to `name`, and now I need to rewrite, changing the URL on the clients, to avoid 404 errors on ~givenname.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~givenname/
RewriteRule ^~givenname/([^/]+)$ ~name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I was unable to do this.

I'm aware that `mod_userdir` looks for specific user info on Unix files (`/etc/passwd`) or whatever is specified on `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, but there's a way to trick it and redirect to the new username?

Thanks.

PS: I'm running a little old Apache 2.2.16 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the [mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) feature for the former username:

```
UserDir disabled givenname
```

After that you could simply use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) for the redirection:

```
Redirect "/~givenname" "/~name"
```

Please upgrade to Apache 2.4 as soon as possible: Apache 2.2 hasn't got updates after 2017, and the 2.2.16 is from July 2010!

Comment: It worked. Thank you!